# Can I use Population Stability Index (PSI) when observations have multiple variables?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, mlops, deployment, data-drift

I understand from resources like [this one](https://medium.com/model-monitoring-psi/population-stability-index-psi-ab133b0a5d42) that the Population Stability Index (PSI) can be used to test for data drift when a machine learning model is in production. However, the resources I have looked at describe PSI in terms of a single variable. Can PSI be applied when observations include multiple variables? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSI is a special case of "SI" which essentially measures the difference between the distribution of *one* variable, over two groups (here, the development data and production data, presumably).
Usually, PSI is suggested for the final score (y_hat_prod), which essentially is a weighted sum of feature variables (Sum_Beta_Xis).

If you wish to calculate the difference in the distribution of the X's *individually*, you can do that; you'd end up with what's normally referred to as Characteristic Stability Index for that individual variable, irrespective of the other Xs or the y_hat.

Comment: Can you please comment on how the weights are determined to compute Sum_Beta_Xis? Also, are there any references you can cite?

Comment: The weights are determined during the model train process, also referred to as `parameters`. A good reference for the SI is https://arize.com/blog-course/population-stability-index-psi/